# Surface integral of a function of two variables over a rectangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I have a problem of which the textbook offers no clarification. The problem states

Evaluate the surface integral of f(x,y) over the rectangle $0 \le x \le a, 0 \le y \le b$ for the function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$

Instinctively, I want to evaluate the integral by

$$S=\int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$

However, when searching about surface integrals I found that they are evaluated by

$$S=\int\int_{D}{}f(x,y,g(x,y))\sqrt{(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})^2+1} dA$$

I have never seen this formula in class so I'm not too sure on whether this is what I should be using.  Also, if I were to use the final integral where in my case $g(x,y)=0$ wouldn't my question reduce to my first integral?

Comment: "Surface integral" normal means what you wanted to do. The other formula is for computing the surface area of the surface described by the domain. Note that it too is a "surface integral" in the first sense.

Comment: So if I were to answer the question the way I initially intended, it should be correct?

Comment: Yes. That's how most people would understand it. You can ask your teacher that this is what s/he expects. Your request for clarification on this will not be viewed as stupid or anything.

Comment: Turns out that is the way my prof wanted it, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Surface area of the surface $z =f(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ is given by

$$
S = \iint_{D} \sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1} \,dA\\
f_x = \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
f_y = \frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1} = \sqrt{2}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\\
$$

Converting to cylindrical coordinates,

$$ S =\sqrt{2}\left( \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{a}^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \frac{1}{r^2}r dr d\theta +  \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}^{b} \frac{1}{r^2}r dr d\theta\right)$$

$$S = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}} \log \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$